# Azure tools - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles

I am trying to create a new project that uses the "Windows Phone Empty Cloud Application" template(Windows Azure Tools) in Visual Studio 2010. When creating a new project it opens a small window with instruction/readme where it says:

> In Solution Explorer, right-click the Windows Azure project, point to Debug and click Start new instance. Wait for the Web role to start and click the Continue to this website (not recommended) link to be able to browse the site despite of the certificate warning.

When I do this, I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
And i have not even started coding yet....
Is the template just broken or??

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25):

With Visual Studio 2013 I started running into the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" errors with Azure projects. In my cases unloading and reloading the cloud and/or role -project has helped (right click on the project, select unload from the context menu)

Comment: Bam!  Nice find, been scratching my head on this one!

Comment: For me reloading , restart didnt worked. I deleted the .suo file that reside along with .sln file after I close the Visual studio and then after deleting .suo file when I launch the Visual Studio and open my project, the issue has gone :)

Comment: I had to close all instances of VS2015. After re-opening the solution the error was gone. Maybe unloading/loading the project didn´t suffice because the same solution was also open in another instance of VS. No need to delete the .suo file.

Comment: Well, thanks so much. it does solve my problem. I guess, it is because my locale setting, which result some encode issue..

Answer (score 2):

After trying the solution above it did not work for me.

We manage to solve the issue starting VS in Administrator mode.

That solve it

Answer (score 0):

Usually it means the .cscfg configuration file is corrupt. In my situation, somehow it contained an invisible character.

Opening each .cscfg file and copy-pasting file content to Notepad and back solved the issue.